# Show that $AΔB=C$ if and only if $A=BΔC$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that $AΔB=C$ if and only if $A=BΔC$. I read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/188384):

> Here's the long messy way. We want to show $A\triangle B = C \iff A = B\triangle C$
>
> $\Rightarrow$: Assume $C = A\triangle B$
>
> Recall $A\triangle B = (A\cup B) - (A\cap B) = (B-A)\cup(A-B)$
>
> $$\begin{align}
> (B\cup C) - (B\cap C) &= (B\cup [(A - B) \cup (B - A)]) - (B\cap [(A\cup B) - (A\cap B)]) \\
> &= ([B\cup (A- B)] \cup (B - A)) - ([B\cap (A\cup B)] - [B\cap (A\cap B)]) \\
> &= ((A\cup B) \cup (B - A)) - \color{red}{(B - (A\cap B))}\\
> &= ((A\cup B) \cup (B - A)) - \color{red}{(B - A)}\\
> &= (A\cup B) - (B - A)\\
> &= A
> \end{align}$$
>
> $\Leftarrow$ is, dare is say, symmetric.

My question is in the part highlighted in red. Why is $A \cap B = A$?

Comment: Don't confuse set subtraction with usual subtraction : the step doesn't happen because $A \cap B = A$. It happens because $B - (A \cap B ) = B-A$, which is true even if $A \cap B \neq A$. Set subtraction has some properties, but is nowhere near being as nice as subtraction for real numbers. It'll be nice if you could attach the answer you're reading from.

Comment: Please include a link to the original answer you are referencing this from. Also, please explain what you've tried so far to understand the reasoning in the answer you are referencing. Please read the advice in [this post on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @GregoryNisbet I included the link.

Comment: You need $A\cup B=S$, where $S$ is entire space.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that A∩B=A (which is not true in general), but rather that B−(A∩B) simplifies to B−A.

Why? because B-A excludes only those elements of B that are also elements of A, that is B-A only excludes elements of B that are elements of (A∩B), but those are also exactly the elements of B excluded by B-(A∩B).

Comment: Neatly done,  may I edit your answer to add MathJax? A quick tutorial can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site). For unions, it's `\cup` and for intersections, it's `\cap`. The rest works out using dollar signs.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that it's not what mentioned in the proof: when you subtract the intersection of A and B from B, by definition, the only relevant part is the elements from A which are originaly in B. Hence, we assume that :
$B-A=B-(A \cap B )$
The proof is by proving equality of sets:
Let $ b \in B-A $. Then $b \in B $ and $b \not\in A$. Hence $b \not\in A \cap B$ , so we got the first side. The other direction is similiar.